# Flask datetime whit GMT-6 in models

Tags: python, flask

I have a class model in Flask for create new user with time creation. the `db.Model` is:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

which is creating record with utc time, I am interesting that date_created value have a different time zone to avoid any post process, I would like to create record with GMT-6.

Comment: Probably something like
`improt pytz` then use pytz to define a timezone to be used `tz = pytz("Etc/GMT-6")`.
To pass it to the `db.Column` would likely need to use a lambda
`date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=lambda: datetime.now(tz=tz))`

Comment: Personally I would always store as UTC.

Comment: thanks @l4sh I will follow your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on what @l4sh has said, UTC is standard when users of your application want to access the timestamp from `date_created`. Imagine this, you have users from different timezones around the world using your application. They post something or access the application at a certain time, say 1500h. This user is in East Africa which is GMT+3. Another user at GMT+6 will see this timestamp as 1800h. This can create an unpleasant user experience in your application.

When you use UTC, the returned timestamp will be the same for all your users. Hence why @l4sh recommends it. But, if you really want to use GMT+6, you can consider to user the package `flask-moment`. It allows for the timezone to be returned based on the configured time of your computer.

To install it, run:

```py
(venv)$ pip3 install flask-moment
```

Initialize it in `__init__.py` as follows:

```py
from flask_moment import Moment

moment = Moment(app)

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Add it to your templates, say the `base.html` as follows within the `scripts` block:

```py
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
{% endblock %}
```

#### Usage

In your template (where you want to show the timestamp), do this:

```py
{% if user.date_created %}
    Date created: {{ moment(user.date_created).format('LLL') }}
{% endif %}
```

Read more from [momentJS documentation](https://momentjs.com/).